# Passing an arbitrary estimation call to a function and adding a parameter

Tags: r

I would like to pass an arbitrary estimation call (e.g., lm or fixest::feols) to a custom function that also takes a dataset. The idea would be to run the same estimation on different subsets of the data (e.g., to bootstrap or run cross-validation), but the below is just a MWE to show the problem.

```
data("mtcars")

foo = function(myfun, data) {
  myfun(data = data)
}

foo(lm(mpg ~ cyl), data = mtcars[1:20, ])
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'mpg' not found
```

The problem seems to be that R tries to evaluate lm. Is there any way to add the parameter data to the lm function call (or any arbitrary function call) before it gets evaluated inside the function? This feels something you could do with [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) or something similar, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Notice that the first parameter defined in foo is a function. On the other hand, the first argument passed to foo is lm object. Which is which? Do you want the first parameter to be a function or an object?? This is confusing

Comment: which is the "parameter data" in your MWE? is it the `mpg ~ cyl`?

Comment: No, the parameter is what gets passed data argument. Of course the formula is a kind of parameter as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the function, `lm`, itself as an argument so `R` does not think it has to evaluated first in the `foo` argument. In this way, `lm` is called inside `foo`:

```
data("mtcars")

foo = function(myfun, myformula, dataset) {
  myfun(formula(myformula), data = dataset)
}

foo(lm, "mpg ~ cyl", dataset = mtcars[1:20, ])


# Call:
#   myfun(formula = formula(myformula), data = dataset)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl  
# 40.249              -3.245
```

Comment: What would this accomplish? Why not simply do `lm(mpg~cyl, mtcars[1:20,])`??

Comment: @Onyambu Indeed it is a little confusing why the need to do so.  But no motivation was given behind this so I just thought maybe OP wanted to loop through different parameters of `foo` or something.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution. The motivation is to facilitate bootstrapping or cross-validation on an arbitrary model. The user would pass the model to fit and the data to fit it on. The function could then run the model on different subsets of the data. So that should be doable with this approach.

I would have ideally liked to find a way to just make it a wrapper around any kind model fitting function - so `run_cv_models(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars))` or similar, but I suspect that'd be much more involved.